# Laravel Migrate SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I'm having errors when trying to migrate to localhost in laravel. Im in the process of learning how to use laravel but I can't connect to phpmyadmin database.

**This is the error message in visual code terminal** 
When I change db host to localhost it gives me a error of PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory")

[image]

**This is my env. file**

```
APP_NAME=LSAPP 
APP_ENV=local 
APP_KEY=base64:Cv3S1V8GT1RKgpfilYmQM4aiM1HoXlwUMfh1oeL424I= 
APP_DEBUG=true APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=lsapp 
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log C
ACHE_DRIVER=file 
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync 
SESSION_DRIVER=file 
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1 
REDIS_PASSWORD=null 
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io 
MAIL_PORT=2525 
MAIL_USERNAME=null 
MAIL_PASSWORD=null 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= 
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1 
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID= 
PUSHER_APP_KEY= 
PUSHER_APP_SECRET= 
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}" 
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

I dit change DBHOST to localhost and also tried other db usernames and db passwords but got no luck. My create posts code is as follow

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->mediumText('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I also changed my AppServiceProvider.php to include Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
I created the empty table also in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

First Try

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

```
php artisan migrate --env=production(or whatever environment)
```

then

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

Comment: should I change db host in my config/database.php file also?

Comment: not needed .just any change in .env then php artisan cache:clear & php artisan config:clear

Comment: got this error now, Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = lsapp and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Comment: composer dump-autoload